# Write data to plist while running app and read them to UITable

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, plist

I want to store the data to plist for the UITable, but so far I am able to read them from plist if they are written there already.I want to write the data while running the app.
Here's the method that saves data to cell in UITableView

```
    -(IBAction)saveAction:(id)sender
{

    Tricks *trick = [[Tricks alloc]init];
    trick.trickName = self.trickLabel.text;
    //trick.trickPhoto = self.ImagePhoto.image;
    [[Tricks trickList]insertObject:trick atIndex:0];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

In detailViewController I can take photo and drop pin on Map.
Photo,pin and text for cell are stored in subclass of NSObject.

loading detailViewController

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"detailTrick"]){
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = nil;

        indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

        DetailViewController *detailViewController  = [segue destinationViewController];
        Tricks *trick = [[Tricks trickList] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        detailViewController.fileText = trick.trickName;
        detailViewController.pinMKPoint = trick.pinNotation;

        }
        detailViewController.trick = trick;
    }
}
```

Code for wiring to plist

```
NSString *trickList = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"trickList" ofType:@"plist"];

    _trick = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:trickList];
    _trickPhotos = [[_trick objectForKey:@"trickPhotos"]objectAtIndex:0];
    _trickNames = [[_trick objectForKey:@"trickNames"]objectAtIndex:0];
    _mapAnnotations = [[_trick objectForKey:@"pinKit"]objectAtIndex:0];
```

I want to write all the data in plist and read them at launch of app.
    Thanks for advices.

Comment: Show the definition of `Tricks` so the data types are clear. Why a plist? What have you tried / errors did you see?

Comment: There's no error but I noticed after a few hours data stored in UITablewView got erased.I've been told it's because of other apps got usage of RAM and app is relying only on multitasking.

@property(strong, nonatomic) UIImage *trickPhoto;
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSString *trickName;
@property(nonatomic) BOOL landed;
@property(nonatomic) MKPointAnnotation *pinNotation;

Comment: Show your code for reading and writing the plist.

Comment: NSString *trickList = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"trickList" ofType:@"plist"];
    
    _trick = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:trickList];
    _trickPhotos = [[_trick objectForKey:@"trickPhotos"]objectAtIndex:0];
    _trickNames = [[_trick objectForKey:@"trickNames"]objectAtIndex:0];
    _mapAnnotations = [[_trick objectForKey:@"pinKit"]objectAtIndex:0];

I can only read....I am asking for advice for writing

Comment: Please update your question with the code. Don't post it in a comment.

Comment: You can't write to the app's resource bundle. It is read-only.

Comment: You also can't directly save images or map annotations into a plist...

Answer (score 0):

You have clearly seen NSDictionary's `-initWithContentsOfFile:` method. Have you looked at [-writeToFile:atomically:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsdictionary_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000140-CBHDBHDB) as well? That seems to be the behavior you are looking for. If you need something more specific please update your question to ask for more specific assistance.

Comment: The problem is the attempt to write the plist to the app's resource bundle.

Comment: First of all, do I even need to store data in plist,if the app is using MVC model and data are stored in NSObject subclass??

Comment: @JozefVrana objects just reside in memory. Any data stored only there will eventually be lost when your application is terminated. If you need this data to persist after a user closes/backgrounds your app then you must store it in some for of persistent store. A plist file is certainly one option.

Comment: As far as the problem writing to your app's resource bundle see [iOS Standard Directories: Where Files Reside](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW4) and [Locating Items in the Standard Directories](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/AccessingFilesandDirectories/AccessingFilesandDirectories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH3-SW3)